# Solublity values interpretation

Tags: solubility, concentration

"Solubility:    Soluble in water (>25 mg/ml), and DMSO (50 mM)."

It happens to be talking about a drug but that's irrelevant to my question.  Does this solubility statement reasonably indicate that I can dissolve 10mg/ml in water and expect it to stay in solution?  if possible, what does the dmso bit mean?  (maybe mM is a typo of mL?)

Comment: Yes at least 25 mg should dissolve per ml of water. Dimethyl sulfoxide (DMSO) is a common organic solvent.

Comment: @MaxW You should post that as an answer.

Comment: wow, great answers everybody, thanks!  I'm asking this as a guest, so I don't seem to see an "Accept Answer" button, which I would click if I could.  all my q's have been answered in prefect detail.  thank you, people!

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

The compound is soluble in water to at least 25 mg/ml - which is (obviously) the same as g/l. Presumably they didn't test at higher concentration.

Alternatively, it is soluble to 50 mM, i.e. mmol/l, in pure DMSO.

Why they would use different units is beyond me,  but I would guess this has to do with the units conventionally used in the two experiments they've run.

Comment: and mM means milli-molar